# Fluent NHibernate Map Enum as Lookup Table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following (simplified)

```
public enum Level
{
    Bronze,
    Silver,
    Gold
}

public class Member
{
    public virtual Level MembershipLevel { get; set; }
}

public class MemberMap : ClassMap<Member>
{
    Map(x => x.MembershipLevel);
}
```

This creates a table with a column called MembershipLevel with the value as the Enum string value.

What I want is for the entire Enum to be created as a lookup table, with the Member table referencing this with the integer value as the FK.

Also, I want to do this without altering my model.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To map an enum property as an int column, use method `CustomType`.

```
public class MemberMap : ClassMap<Member>
{
    Map( x => x.MembershipLevel ).CustomType<int>();
}
```

In order to keep the enum and lookup table in sync, I would add the lookup table and data to your sql scripts. An integration test can verify that the enum and lookup table values are the same.

If you wanted SchemaExport to create this table, add a class and mapping for it.

```
public class MembershipLevel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}

public class MembershipLevelMap : ClassMap<MembershipLevel>
{
    Id( x => x.Id );
    Map( x => x.Code );
}
```

If you are creating the table with SchemaExport, you will need to populate it as well:

```
foreach (Level l in Enum.GetValues( typeof( Level ))) {
    session.Save( new MembershipLevel{ Id = (int) l, Code = l.ToString() });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use NHibernate to create the lookup table (as part of SchemaExport)

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't do that because your Enum declaration is not dynamic, or simpler, it doesn't change without recompiling, while your lookup table may change at any moment. If the Enum's and lookup table's values don't match, what's next?

Another reason is if you change the Enum (in code), you'd have to synchronise it with the database table. Since Enums don't have an incremental key (PK), they can't be synchronised so simple. Let's say you remove one Enum member from your code and recompile it, what is supposed to happen? And if you change a value?

I hope I made my objections to this approach clear. So I strongly recommend storing the name or the value of your enum members. To store it by name, just map like this:

```
public class MemberMap : ClassMap<Member>
{
    Map(x => x.MembershipLevel, "level")
        .CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<Level>>()
        .Not.Nullable();
}
```

To store the values, do as @Lachlan posted in his answer.

Or if you really need a lookup table and wants to use an Enum with strict checking, create a normal model with *PK* (or use value for this), *KEY* and *VALUE*. Create your enum with your static members, and make the application query the database for the *names* and *values* when you start it. If things don't match, do whatever you need. Additionally, this doesn't guarantee your table won't change while your program is running, so you better be sure it doesn't.

Comment: It's pretty easy to assign an explict value to specific elements in the enum, so it's pretty easy to keep them in sync.

Comment: There's also a considerable amount of confusion, at least that I perceive, due to the overloading of the term "lookup table". In some cases it seems to just refer to a table for which a 'lookup' is performed via a foreign key relationship. That seems to be the case you're describing as well. But what the example in this question describes is also sometimes known as a "code table". The reason why I, and I imagine others, would like to represent those with an enum is that there's no real way to avoid them being 'magic numbers'. The enum just documents what would otherwise be numeric constants.

Comment: @KennyEvitt I agree that enums are superior to _magic numbers_. What I wanted to point out is that it's easy to change them in the database and forget to change them in your application's code. However, if they're enums in the database as well, you can reference them by their name instead of their value (ordinal). That's what the mapping above accomplishes. If you ever change the value of your enum(s) in the database, your code should still works as expected. It shouldn't be necessary to change your application's code unless you're breaking something badly.

Comment: We must have different intuitions about what is more likely. I'd expect changes to the name or description of a code far more often than changes to its ID, but maybe that's because I've personally used enums with IDs. Someone suggested integration tests to check that enums and code table match; that seems wise. Regardless, changing IDs or names of code tables should be considered a potentially breaking change for all of its depndents.